# stream_set_chunk_size(): The chunk size cannot be larger than 2147483647

Tags: php, laravel

php artisan route:cache command throws the error:

stream_set_chunk_size(): The chunk size cannot be larger than 2147483647

at vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:144

Please help me out to solve this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your config/database.php

```
'charset' => 'utf8',
'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
```